# How restrict scala private scope to one object only?

Tags: scala, class, object, access-modifiers

I am trying to specify that `val` constant is visible only to one object:

```
object Config {
    private[my.pack.MyObject] val Some = Option("String")
}

// in package my.pack
object MyObject {
    val Other = Config.Some
}
```

While compiling this I get an error:

```
[error] C:\path\Config.scala:17: ']' expected but '.' found.
[error]   private[my.pack.MyObject] val Some = Option("String")
[error]              ^
```

What is wrong? As I read about access qualifiers they can be a class or object, not a package, am I wrong?

Comment: So you want to restrict access to `val Some` to an object other than the assigning object? I may be just confused, but should `Config` be able to assign a value to `Some` when it has no access to it? Can you explain a bit more about the use case?

Comment: That would be pretty weird if you could do scoping such that the `Config` object doesn't have access to its own `val`.

Answer (score 6):

From [the Scala Language specification, section 5.2.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#private):

> A private modifier can be *qualified* with an identifier *C* (e.g. `private[C]`) that **must denote a class or package enclosing the definition**. Members labeled with such a modifier are accessible respectively only from code inside the package *C* or only from code inside the class *C* and its companion module.

(bold mine -- note that "class or package" also admits "object", not sure if this is standard language in the spec, or a bug in the spec)

So your example does not compile because `my.pack.MyObject` is not an *enclosing* declaration of `val Some`.